# Accessing the right member based on the object type

Tags: c#

PlayerBase is a base class for FieldPlayer and GoalKeeper. I have stateMachine memeber in FieldPlayer and GoalKeeper. But in MyList a FieldPlayer and a GoalKeeper are both treated as PlayerBase. How do I make sure that I get the stateMachine for the right type? Should I somehow check for type and then typecast?

```
foreach (PlayerBase p in MyList)
{
 // Here I need to access p.stateMachine for FieldPlayer or GoalKeeper, depends what p is.
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is stateMachine not a member of PlayerBase?

Comment: having to check for the actual type when using polymorphism is a code smell. Why do you have to differentiate?

Comment: nope, can't do that, it is a specific member i implemented in different way for both of FieldPlayer and GoalKeepeer

Comment: or put another way: Why isn't stateMachine not a member of PlayerBase - is it different for FieldPlayer and GoalKeepers?

Comment: well yea that is what I just said

Answer (score 2):

The member should be declared in `PlayerBase` as a property. Perhaps this is an abstract declaration, or at the least a virtual declaration. The property could then be overriden in your derived classes if they need something other than the default behavior.

```
abstract class PlayerBase
{
    public abstract TheType StateMachine { get; set; }  // declare here

    // if PlayerBase is not abstract, you can declare the property as: 
    // public virtual TheType StateMachine { get; set; }
}

class FieldPlayer : PlayerBase 
{
    public override TheType StateMachine { get; set; } // implement here
}
```

You *typically* don't want to be in the position of doing type-checking in code that deals with the base type. More specified (or derived) types should be able to be directly substituted for the base without the code caring.

Comment: that is the problem, it is a specific implementation, stateMachine for GoalKeeper differs quite a lot from the one for FieldPlayer.

Comment: I don't agree with this. Why couple the `PlayerBase` to the `StateMachine`?

Comment: @pokoko, that's why you want to make it a virtual (or abstract, if the base is abstract) member, so the children can override the default behavior with their own implementation. But the consuming code (the method dealing with `List<PlayerBase>` need not care.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, just saw that the OP has it wired up this way.

Comment: @Jon, it depends. From his description, he has one class, two children, each with the same property but a different implementation. If it turns out he has *more than two* children, but *only these two* have this property, then I agree with you, perhaps `PlayerBase` isn't the place for it.

Comment: But stateMachine is of different type. The stateMachine for FieldPlayer is type StateMachine<FieldPlayer> and the one for GoalKeeper is StateMachine<GoalKeeper >. So if I have virtual member stateMachine in the base class, what type will it be?

Comment: @pokoko, OK, that's a good distinction. Do you have other members of the children that are *also* generic? This problem is evolving. You could make the base generic as `PlayerBase<T>` generic with a `StateMachine<T>`, or you could revisit your `StateMachine` abstraction and extract a non-generic interface from it, so that one machine can be substituted for another *as far as the base/consuming code is concerned.* Try this approach, try Darin's. See what gives you the least trouble or the most flexibility.

Comment: Anthony I don't understand the second part, "extract a non-generic interface from it, so that one machine can be substituted for another"? The first one is an option I think about yes.

Comment: What I mean is your `StateMachine<>` is generic. Does it need to be? As an implementation detail, sure, perhaps it does. But does code that *works with it* need it to be generic? Does code that interacts with it need to know it is a machine that only deals with type T? If not, then the T might very well be hidden or abstracted away. Such as `StateMachine<T> : IStateMachine`, and it is `IStateMachine` that is exposed.

Comment: But here's what I suggest, once again. Try either suggestion presented in the answers. Work with the code a bit. If in a few more hours, you still have questions, I suggest opening a new question, providing more detail (not *too* much, but I think you'll agree your question here left out some relevant info), and you might get more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (PlayerBase p in MyList)
{
    var fp = p as FieldPlayer;
    if (fp != null)
    {
        // p is a FieldPlayer => you can access the stateMachine property
        Console.WriteLine(fp.stateMchine);
    }
}
```